# Can't find element with a specific data dash attribute that I added dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

When I add a data-itemid attribute to an element, I can not find that element using

```
$('someSelector').find( '[data-itemid="' + itemid + '"]' )
```

Doing

```
$('#id-of-element-i-added-the-attribute-to').data('itemid')
```

returns the correct data.

```
$('#id-of-element-i-added-the-attribute-to').attr('data-itemid')
```

returns an empty string.

`$('someSelector').find( '[data-itemid="' + itemid + '"]' )` works for elements that initially have that data dash attribute, but not for dynamically added attributes.

I add the attribute like this  `$('#'+listItemId).data('itemid', itemId)`;

How can i find the element that has that dynamically added data-itemid attribute with specific value.

This selectors don't work as well (they return empty arrays):

```
$('*').find( '[data-itemid="' + itemid + '"]' )
$('[data-itemid="' + itemid + '"]' )
$('[data-itemid="16"]' )
```

Comment: `$('#'+listItemId).data('itemid', itemId)` does not add an *attribute*. jQuery just stores that data internally. Use `.attr` to set attribute values, or use Rory's answer.

Comment: `$('someSelector').find( '[data-itemid=" + itemid + "]' )` is surely a typo? (As it looks for a `data-itemid` that is literally ` + itemid + `, rather than using the value of hte `itemid` variable.) I **do not** understand why people can't use copy and paste... ;-)

Comment: I edit the question, change `$('someSelector').find( '[data-itemid=" + itemid + "]' )` to `$('someSelector').find( '[data-itemid="' + itemid + '"]' )`, but not pass review. :P

Comment: @pktangyue: It's the kind of thing it's best to leave to the OP -- in case it *is* actually what they have in their code!

Comment: @James didn't know jQuery stores the data-attributes internally, very useful information, thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes it's a typo, will edit it right away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `filter` to find dynamically added `data` attributes. Try this:

```
var $elementsWithDataAttr = $('someSelector .class').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('itemid') != "";
});
// do something with $elementsWithDataAttr ...
```